# What is the phase spectrum and why does it have values for the given graph of a simple sine function

Tags: matlab, physics, transmission

I understand the first 2 graphs, the time domain representation and the frequency domain representation (amplitude spectrum) but I cannot wrap my head around the phase spectrum. Why does it contain a value at f = 100? Is it linked with the bandwidth of the system?

[image: Screenshot of MATLAB slides displaying equations and charts for a sinusoidal signal, time domain and frequency domain]

Answer (score 2):

The phase plot is just showing that the phase of the associated sine wave at that frequency is -pi/2.  This results from the Fourier transform of a sine wave bing two components, one at positive and one at negative frequency, one with a phase to +90 degrees (pi/2) and the other with a phase of -90 degrees (-pi/2).  See [The Fourier Transform of the Sine and Cosine Functions](https://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/sinusoids.php) for more details